# How to make responsive website work on mobile?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I've just built this website [wwww.griyapustaka.com](http://www.griyapustaka.com). Actually this is responsive website. But It's doesn't work on mobile. If I opened on mobile, it was just blank. Where is the problem???

Comment: looks to me its fully responsive and it opens in mobile.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox's Responsive Design view and on my Android phone. What mobile platform are you trying it on where it's just show up blank?

Answer (score 2):

your website is already responsive but the there is a problem in your CSS.while anyone scroll on your website it doesn't works check out this [ResponsiveCheker](http://responsivedesignchecker.com/%20www.griyapustaka.com)

Answer (score 1):

Add this meta tags :

```
<meta content="width=device-width,height=device-height,inital-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
```

Comment: this amounts to a code only answer with no explanation whatsoever of why this would help. Answers like these are not very useful even if the code does help. Many would disagree with using `user-scalable=no`

Comment: oke I will try,, Just add, or have to remove my meta tag too??

Comment: @charlietfl It was because of my English I just want to help ! no need to make me down

Comment: I am not trying to make you down, I was just explaining how good answers work

Comment: @ Ayuktia  yes add this code and if you want as  @charlietfl said you can change `width=device-width,height=device-height,inital-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=n` with your needs .

Comment: @charlietfl  thank you mr. guider ...